# navigator.camera.getPicture doesn’t call success callback - ionic framework - cordova

Tags: android, cordova, camera, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-framework

I am using navigator.camera for taking pictrues. The success and error call back is not getting called most of the time. I have installed cordova camera plugin

I am using

ionic 1.2.8

cordova  3.5.0-0.2.7

org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.3 "Camera"

Shown below is the code I use.

```
$scope.takePicture =  function takePicture()    {
    var success = function onSuccess (FILE_URI){
    console.log("something" + FILE_URI)
    console.log(FILE_URI);
    $localstorage.setObject("file",FILE_URI);
    $rootScope.picData = FILE_URI;
}

var error = function onError () {
    console.log("Error")
    alert("error")
}

console.log("Taking picture");
navigator.camera.getPicture(success,error,{
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
        });
```

};

Answer (score 3):

It started working perfectly when I disconnected my phone from my system. Something wrong was happening when my phone was in developer mode.

Given below are few links which might help others facing similar issue

[PhoneGap camera restarts the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368091/phonegap-camera-restarts-the-application)

[How to prevent Android to restart application after calling camera intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617398/how-to-prevent-android-to-restart-application-after-calling-camera-intent)

[Cordova / Samsung Galaxy SIII - Camera Crashes app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615190/cordova-samsung-galaxy-siii-camera-crashes-app)

[Phonegap camera android kills cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273429/phonegap-camera-android-kills-cordova)

[Cordova plugin callback received after second plugin call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653961/cordova-plugin-callback-received-after-second-plugin-call)

Posting this here so that  this will help someone else. :)